# help gnome-panel

Tags: gnome-panel

When i install Ubuntu 13.10 updating, i did not get upper bar
i have this problem with gnome-panel.

```
(gnome-panel:6959): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion 'accelerator != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:6959): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'


(gnome-panel:6959): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion 'accelerator != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:6959): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

I  do not know nothing about computer, what can i do?